# Passing object key as an argument for parameter retrieval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I've built an AngularJS factory:

```
angular.module('app.services', [])

.factory('StorageService', function($localStorage) {
    $localStorage.$default({
        objA : ['foo','bar'],
        objB : []
    });
    var _getByKey = function(storageItem){
        return $localStorage.storageItem;
    }

    return {
        get : _getByKey
    };

});
```

In my controller, I'm trying to retrieve it as such:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, StorageService) {
    console.log(StorageService.get(objA));
}
```

I will be having several objects stored in the localStorage and I want a flexibility to retrieve them via the factory rather than injecting the $localStorage dependency together with the factory.

I strongly believe the issue is lying in the factory's parameter passing. Some JavaScript hack that my brain is not processing. LOL. Any ideas? ^_^

UPDATE: Sorry guys, I totally forgot the error~ Basically, when this code is executed, I get "ReferenceError: objA is not defined"

Comment: try returning {
        get : _getByKey
    }; it seems as if you have a type error in your code

Comment: You mention will have several objects stored, I can't see calling each object by its name being sustainable: `StorageService.get(objA)` Unless you have a way of keeping track of said objects. Maybe smt to bear in mind in you factory design.

Comment: @boroboris sorry, indeed it was_getByKey, I wrongly typed in the question.. But that's not the fix.. :(

Comment: @Jax These objects will indeed have a specific naming convention that they will follow and very semantic eventually.. But they will be retrieved, and updated a lot, so calling it using the StorageService.get(objA) will definitely benefit a lot..

Comment: what is the problem again

Comment: @CognitiveDesire Oh god, I'm so sorry! Forgot to include the actual question. So when I execute this, I get the following error: "ReferenceError: objA is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax here is not quite right.  What you are *trying* to do is pass the property name you want to retrieve;  What you are *actually* doing is passing a variable, which hasn't been declared yet.

So the first part you need to change is:

```
console.log(StorageService.get('objA'));
```

Pass a string value, rather than a variable.

Inside your `.get()` method, you are attempting to retrieve the property based on the value that was passed in, but what you are actually doing is looking for the property `storageItem`, which won't exist.  If you want to use the value of `storageItem`, you need to use the bracket syntax.

```
return $localStorage[storageItem];
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sU00SgcKHJD0tUNKmT8F?p=preview)

Comment: thank you so much! That actually worked! The main issue was indeed the variable vs property. Bonus on the bracket syntax. I was on the verge of thinking that localStorage was kept as an object and could be retrieved using javascript-dot-notation. Thank you good sir! It's totally working now~